# How to do the filter operator from a list of a list in rxjava

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-kotlin

Good afternoon.
So I got a list with a list inside like this:

```
    {
  "category" : [
    {
      "name": "Bathroom",
      "products": [
        {
          "name": "Sink01"
        },
        {
          "name": "Shower01"
        }
      ]
    },{
      "name": "Kitchen",
      "products": [
        {
          "name": "Table"
        },
        {
          "name": "Stove"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So if the user for example selects the category "Bathroom" I want to use rxjava to filter the list of products from the category "Bathroom" and if they select the category "Kitchen" I want to get the list of products from the category "Kitchen".

This is what I've tried so far:

```
    fun getProducts(category: Category): Single<MutableList<Product>> {
         return service.getProductsByCategories().filter{ response ->
             response.categoriesList.forEach {
                if (it.name == category.name) {
                  category.products
                }
             }
         }
    }
```

Right now I am getting "Typed mismatch. Requieres: `Single<MutableList<Product>>`, Found: `Maybe<MyResponse!>!`"

Why is this happening?
What is the correct way to filter?

Thanks in advance.

Greetings

Comment: Could you clarify what type the `service.getProductsByCategories()` returns?
Also, whatever that type is, I doubt its method `filter` expects a lambda that returns a list of 'things' instead of a boolean (`true` or `false`).

Comment: It returns a Single<List<Categories>>, inside each category there is a list of products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unroll the `getProductsByCategories` response, filter for the right category, map in the product list, then convert it to the desired output type:

```
getProductsByCategories()
.flattenAsObservable { it }
.filter { it.name == category.name }
.map { it.products }
.single( ArrayList<Product>() )
```

Comment: list -> list // what type should list be?

Comment: Right, this is Kotlin. Just `{ it }` then. Updated the answer.

Comment: made some minor changes to make it build

Comment: getProductsByCategories()
            .flattenAsObservable {
                it.categoriesList
            }
            .filter {
                it.name == category
            }
            .map { it.products }
            .single( ArrayList() )